# Error al buscar los templates en Cobigen, DevonFw

Tags: java, java-ee

Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto con DevonFw, que es un framework de desarrollo fullstack, con Java EE en el back y Angular en el front. El caso es que tiene una herramienta integrada llamada Cobigen, que básicamente es una herramienta que te genera código. Esta herramienta tiene unos templates con el código a general. El caso es que si hago el HealthCheck de Cobigen, me dice:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at:
```

Y tras el at me aparecen un montón de direcciones, tanto del propio framework (DevonFw) como del propio IDE que viene integrado en el framework (Eclipse). Si le doy a actualizar templates, me dice que me los descarga y que todo correcto, pero tanto a la hora de hacer el healthcheck como de generar los templates, me da error porque no me los encuentra. La documentación dice que en caso de que se de este error, que has de forzar la descarga de los templates y que verás un nuevo folder en el workspace, pero no me aparece nada. ¿Cómo podría solucionar esto? Gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he resuelto. La solución es darle a "Adapt Templates", ya que te importará Cobigen de forma automática, y con las importaciones todo irá correcto.